# Read VARBINARY(MAX) from SQL Server to C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net

I need to read data row from SQL Server 2008. The type of one of the columns is `VARBINARY(MAX)`. In C# I want to use out parameter to read it (and given scenario satisfies the needs mostly).

But I need to specify the parameter variable size to fill the C# variable.
Here I assume that 8000 is enough... But who knows:

```
database.AddOutParameter(command, "vbCertificate", DbType.Binary, 8000);
```

So the questions are:

1. What is the size of MAX in number for SQL Server 2008?
2. Is this ok to use out parameter for this scenario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @marc_s said, I will just want to add something.

There are two data types

**binary** [ ( n ) ]

Fixed-length binary data with a length of n bytes, where n is a value from 1 through 8,000. The storage size is n bytes.

**varbinary** [ ( n | max) ]

Variable-length binary data. n can be a value from 1 through 8,000. max indicates that the maximum storage size is 2^31-1 (equals int.MaxValue i.e. 2,147,483,647) bytes. The storage size is the actual length of the data entered + 2 bytes. The data that is entered can be 0 bytes in length.

if you are specifying max then your concern should be with varbinary instead of binary

<del>database.AddOutParameter(command, "vbCertificate", DbType.Binary, 8000);</del>

database.AddOutParameter(command, "vbCertificate", SqlDbType.VarBinary, int.MaxValue);

Answer (score 5):

The max size for `VARBINARY(MAX)` is 2 GB of data - 2'147'483'648 bytes.

In your case, when defining it in C#, I would recommend using `int.MaxValue` as the value to provide.

And yes, if you want to get the array of bytes back from the SQL Server 2008 table, then you can most definitely use an `out` parameter.

Comment: The SqlClient size for max types is `-1`. The Framework understands this as a `max` type.

Comment: @Remus Rusanu: ok, thanks - good to know! (but I've had no trouble with int.MaxValue either, so far :-)

Comment: Could you please tell me why we definity use out parameter if we need to read varbinary(max) ?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen an explicit size anywhere for MAX.  Have you tried executing this using DbType.Object?  That is defined on msdn as a general type for any type not explicitly defined.  I would try that and see if it works or not.  Otherwise, I would probably stick to DbType.Binary as you chose.